# Symbol is element of, how to print in c?

Tags: c, printf, symbols

Is it possible to display the mathematical symbol for *"is element of"* in C?

[image: element of]

For example:

```
printf("a is element of A");
```

Comment: Unicode U+2208: ∈  Does your environment support unicode?

Comment: @dvnrrs: that's for a different language, C++, though the topics are related.

Comment: AShelly: Yes, dvnrrs: Thank you

Comment: If the environment supports Unicode, then `\u2208 or \U00002208 would identify the symbol.

Comment: In UTF-8, it would be '\xe2\x88\x88' if your locale can be set to UTF-8 (or if it already is UTF-8). Otherwise, you would need to have a way to print Unicode strings. Some platforms allow you to use `wprintf(L"a \u2208 A\n");`, assuming `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is `#define`d. Otherwise, we will need to know what platform you're working with.